# does php have built-in array functions that can sort/assign values for boolean result?

Tags: javascript, php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of orders, key represents order#.  each element contains an array of employees that can fulfill those orders represented by employee number.

example

```
[0] =>         // <-- order#
    [0] => 0,
    [1] => 1,
    [2] => 2

[1] =>
    [0] => 0,
    [1] => 1,
    [2] => 2

[2] =>
    [0] => 3

[3] =>
    [0] => 3
```

so order 0 can be fulfilled by employee 0,1, or 2. 
order 1 as well.
orders 2 and 3 can only be fulfilled by employee 3.

i need to return bool which is true if each order has one unique employee to fulfill it.  so in this case return false because only one employee is available to fulfill orders 2 and 3 and cant be assigned to both.

i hope that makes sense.  tapping this out on my phone agh

Comment: As agreed, I can prepare a JS answer to this.

Comment: thank you much.  i am very grateful for any help. let me know if any questions

Comment: Asking for an existing "array function" is pretty optimistic here, as that's a non-trivial problem. [Constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) *may* be a viable approach here.

Comment: @deceze Agreed.  My first impulse was to suggest something using `array_map`, but it's more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a php function I wrote quickly that does what you want, I have quickly tested it and it seems to work properly.

```
<?php

function compare($orders){

    if(sizeof($orders) == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    $quantity = array();
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if(sizeof($order) == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        foreach ($order as $employee) {
            if(array_key_exists($employee, $quantity)){
                $quantity[$employee]++;
            }
            else{
                $quantity[$employee] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    $chosenEmployees = array_keys($quantity, min($quantity));
    $chosenEmployee = $chosenEmployees[0];

    $length = array();
    foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
        $length[$key] = sizeof($order);
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($orders); $i++) {
        $chosenOrders = array_keys($length, min($length));
        foreach ($chosenOrders as $orderKey) {
            if(in_array($chosenEmployee, $orders[$orderKey])){
                unset($orders[$orderKey]);
                foreach ($orders as $key1 => $order) {
                    foreach ($order as $key2 => $employee) {
                        if($employee == $chosenEmployee){
                            unset($orders[$key1][$key2]);
                        }           

                    }
                }
                return compare($orders);
            }
            else{
                unset($length[$orderKey]);
            }
        }
    }

}
$out = compare($orders);
?>
```

To use it, type compare($your_array_name), and the function will return 0 (false) or 1 (true).
Hope it helps.

**Edit:**
I doubt you'll find this code anywhere else because I wrote it for this question.
I have been working  on proof and can prove that when the function returns true, it is true.

The function returned true.
=> The orders array is empty.
=> Before that, the orders array contained one order that can be done by at least employee one.
=> Before that, the orders array contained two orders that can be done respectively by at least employee one and employee two.
Via recurrence, we can deduce that n steps before the end, there were n orders, all doeable by at least one unique employee.
If n = size of initial array, we can conclude that if the function returns true, it is correct.
If this proof is not correct, please let me know. I will edit my post again if I find proof for the second half.

Comment: There *has* to be a way to do this without *4* levels of nested loops

Comment: An explanation of the algorithm would be good; this is terribly dense…

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't got the time to put explain at the moment. The idea behind this recursive function is to count the amount of times each person appears, and the amount of different people that can do each task, hence the $quantity and $length variables. After thay, we examine who is the least available and remove the task that has the least people who can solve it and remove him from the other tasks. If the list of objectives is empty on the next call of the function, the tasks can be spread out. If there is a task with no available people (ie an empty array), we conclude we can't.

Comment: If I have the time, I'll update the answer with proper explanations

Comment: @J.Quick I'll give you that; it works. I haven't been able to find a combination that gives the wrong output after fiddling with it for a while

Comment: great job.  i did have one rare test scenario where it didnt pass but its more likely my own code causing this.  thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `array_reduce` and `array_diff` to speculatively assign employees to orders.

```
//Each step tries to add another employee id to the $carry array
function calc($carry, $item) 
{
    if (!$carry) {
        $carry = array();
    }
    $diff = array_diff($item, $carry);
    if (count($diff) > 0) {
        array_push($carry, reset($diff));
    }
    return $carry;
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return count($a) - count($b);
}

function checkCondition($arrayToCheck) 
{
    uasort($arrayToCheck, 'cmp');
    $reduced = array_reduce($arrayToCheck, "calc");

    //If we have a shorter array than the number of orders, we have a problem
    return count($reduced) == count($arrayToCheck);
}

$o = array(
    array(0,1,2),
    array(0,1,2),
    array(3),
    array(3),
);

$result = checkCondition($o);

echo $result + " " + $result ? "Good" : "Bad";  //Should be Bad

$o = array(
    array(0,1,2),
    array(0,1,2),
    array(1),
    array(3),
);

$result = checkCondition($o);

echo $result + " " + $result ? "Good" : "Bad";  //Should be Good
```

Sorting the array first avoids the problem of "assigning" a worker to an order who MUST be assigned to a later order.

Comment: @WilliamPerron Good point.  I've edited in a fix.  TBF, this is a pretty simple approach.  I haven't tested it thoroughly.

Comment: I like this solution: it's simple and concise

Answer (score 2):

### Algorithm

Your main issue is about the algorithm. As discussed, the language is of secondary importance.

What you want is to

> *check if each order can be assigned one employee and each
>   employee assigned one or no order*

You can draw it like a graph:

- nodes are **orders and employees**
- links are **possible assignments**

So you want to remove all necessary links so that

- each employee node has **one or no** link left, and
- each order node still has **one** (or more) link left

If you succeed, you have a solution and want the algorithm to return `true`. Otherwise, it should return `false`.

---

EDIT: J. Quick found [an incredibly simple implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668924/8122487) that works. I would love to get a proof of it or a reference of where he found it though.

So I explain it here:

1. If **orders** is empty, return `true`
2. If any order of **orders** has no employee, return `false`
3. Get employee **e** with least number of orders
4. Get **e**'s order **o** with least number of employees
5. Remove **e** and **o** from **orders**
6. Repeat from 1.

---

### JavaScript implementation

```
function areAllOrdersFulfilled(orders) {
    while (orders.length !== 0) {
        if (undefined !== orders.find( o => o.length === 0))
            // An order has no employee to fulfill it
            return false;
        // Get employee and order to remove
        let employees = [];
        orders.forEach( order => {
            order.forEach( employee => {
                employees[employee] = (employees[employee] || 0) + 1;
            });
        });
        let employeeToRemove = employees.indexOf(employees.slice().sort()[0]), // Employee with less orders
            orderToRemove = orders
                .sort( (o1, o2) => o1.length - o2.length ) // In-place sort orders
                .findIndex( o => o.includes(employeeToRemove)); // Order with less employees
        // Remove
        orders.splice(orderToRemove,1);
        orders = orders.map( o => o.filter(e => e !== employeeToRemove) )
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can run it like that:

```
const orders = [
    [0,1,2],
    [0,1,2],
    [3],
    [3]
];

console.log(areAllOrdersFulfilled(orders));
```

Comment: thank you RaphaMex.  i appreciate the explanation and your time on this.  im gonna give jquick the check.  he came up with good answer and has few points.  hope you understand.  thanks again. +++1

Comment: @BrianPatterson: No worries, I learnt something myself here. Why do you open bounty when you already have an answer? That's nice from you anyway.