# How to count different values of an object inside an array

Tags: mysql, node.js

In a database i have two colums: `id` and `value`. I want to check how many difrent `id`'s there is in my `result`, how can i do that?

I have tried to think of an solution, but i haven't succeed more that `countDifferentId(){// do some magic calculations}`

`result` looks like this:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 76561198115203520,
    value: 73 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 76561198115029751,
    value: 73 }
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 76561198115702984,
    value: 73 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 76561198115203520,
    value: 73 } ]
```

So the result of `countDifferentId()` should be 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the job on javascript side, here you go:

```
const rowDataPackets = [
    {
        id: 76561198115203520,
        value: 73
    },
    {
        id: 76561198115029751,
        value: 73
    },
    {
        id: 76561198115702984,
        value: 73
    },
    {
        id: 76561198115203520,
        value: 73
    }
];


function countDifferentId(array){
    // Object with key=id to count unique ids and value is true (or whatever)
    const uniqueIds = array.reduce((acc, data) => Object.assign(acc, {[data.id]:true}) , {});
    // Number of unique ids is the number of keys
    return Object.keys(uniqueIds).length;
}

console.log(countDifferentId(rowDataPackets));
```

Comment: This worked! Very compact and fast, just what i needed

Comment: Note: i changed `const uniqueIds = rowDataPackets.reduce` to `const uniqueIds = array.reduce`

Comment: Good catch! happy it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to do so in a group by query? There're lots of examples here. e.g.

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

[MySQL Query with count and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344810/mysql-query-with-count-and-group-by)

etc.

If you have only server request from API, you may want . to create a hash table like
{
id: count
}

Comment: I hoped for a JS solution as i think it is faster for me

Comment: JS is not necessarily faster, it's often better share work between servers. `Group by` is a good option. If there's a lot of rows to fetch and you **just want to count**, even better do a `select count(distinct id) from...`

Comment: @RaphaMex the rows will not exceed 100 and i need to make a call every 1 second, is it still better?

Comment: I made a pure JS solution, if you want to give it a try and compare. 100 rows every second, that's not a problem for either solution. I was just commenting in case you had thousands of rows, better relieve your network.

Comment: @McMuffin Hey, you may also try lodash library. const result = _.countBy(dataArray, 'id');

Comment: i agree that doing this at the query level is ideal, but sometimes its not a viable option depending on project dynamics.

Comment: Yep, especially when you work with third-party API responses

Answer (score 1):

function grabs all values from one array column and returns as an array.

then for loop uses an array to store counted values, checking the array each time to ensure values counted only once.

```
function getCol(myarray, col){ 
    var column = []; 
    for(var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++){ 
        column.push(myarray[i][col]); 
    } 
    return column; 
    }

    cols = getCol(result, 'id');
    var count = 0;
    var used = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<cols.length;i++){
         if(!used.indexOf(cols[i])){
               used.push(cols[i]);
               count++;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: crappy stack app posted this twice ugh

Comment: Indeed it is crap

Comment: If i wanted to call `getCol()` how would i parse the MySQL `result` into the function?

Comment: getCol(result,'id');

Comment: You've nice built-in javascript function to do this. Try to rewrite your function with `forEach` or `reduce`

Comment: @RaphaMex -  can you look at my php question please.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654274/php-multi-dimensional-array-unique-sort

Comment: @BrianPatterson: I could help you in many languages, but not php, sorry

Comment: @RaphaMex - javascript works too :)  have no idea how to parse it logically.  ugh